# Prove that the interval $(0,1)$ and the Cartesian product $(0,1)\times(0,1)$ have the same cardinality.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

(Hint: Use the Schröder-Bernstein theorem.)
I know I need to find two injective functions but I'm yet to find something that makes sense.

Comment: Did you look up this theorem? Have you thought about this at all?

Comment: Is the Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem the same thing? If not, asker deserves the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: Yes it is the same. The asker needs to find two injective functions, one from $(0,1)$ to $(0,1)\times (0,1)$ and another from $(0,1)\times (0,1)$ to $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $I = (0,1)$. We clearly have an injective function

$$\begin{align*}f: I &\to I\times I \\ x & \mapsto (x,0). \end{align*}$$

We are going to construct an injective function $g: I\times I \to I$.

Let $(a,b)\in I\times I$. And let

$$a = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k2^{-k} \qquad b = \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k2^{-k}$$

the binary expressions of $a$ and $b$ ($a_k,b_k \in \{0,1\}$ for all $k \geq 1$). In other words, $a = 0.a_1a_2a_3,\ldots $ and $b = 0.b_1b_2b_3\ldots$.

Then let $g$ be such that

$$(a,b) \mapsto \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k2^{1-2k} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k2^{-2k}$$

in other words, $(a,b) \mapsto 0.a_1b_1a_2b_2a_3b_3\ldots$.

You should have no problem proving that this is injective.

---

We should note that when we express $a$ and $b$ in binary we don't allow for repeating $1's$, e.g. we express $1/2$ as $0.1$ and not as $0.0111111\ldots$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Perhaps a simpler $f:I\times I\to I$ would be $f(a,b)=a+b\bmod{1}$?

Comment: @LaarsHelenius That's not injective since then
$$f\left(\dfrac{1}{4},\dfrac{1}{4}\right) = \dfrac{1}{2} = f\left(\dfrac{3}{4},\dfrac{3}{4}\right).$$

Comment: Right. It's surjective but not injective.

Comment: @LaarsHelenius Indeed, with your $f$ we have $f(I\times\{0\}) = I$. And for any $x\in I$ we have $f^{-1}(x) \cong I$. Wich is very far from injective.